# Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'helpfulness' not found

Tags: r

```
>hyp1.model1<-clmm(helpfulness~reflectiontype+session+(1+reflectiontype|participant),data=hyp1data)
>summary(hyp1.model1) #summary was produced but I won't replicate it here
>anova(hyp1.model1,type="II")
Error in eval(predvars,data,env):object 'helpfulness' not found
```

I want to run an anova on hyp1.model1 - The model ran fine initially and 'helpfulness' has not come up as a problem in any of my other code using this variable. R has linked with the data set totally fine up until this point and there appears to be no difference between the variable column heading in the data set and the variable label in R (hence all other code has recognised it).

Why is this suddenly a problem when I want to run an anova?

Comment: what package is `clmm` from? can you share your data? Does `anova` support  `clmm` model types?

Comment: Hi Steph, I don't think you can run a type II anova on mixed models with ordinal. If you need to test the significance of terms, I guess you have to do anova(fullmodel,reducedmodel)

Comment: I found a tutorial that explains how to use the Anova command (with capital A) using some different packages. I've posted a link below and it seems to have worked o.k.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `helpfulness` is not in your data frame `hyp1data`. When you create the model in your first line, it is found in the local environment (all of the variables you have created in R). However when you run the third line, the code specifically looks for `helpfulness` in the data frame you have specified. If it isn't there, it would fail like this.

Try:

```r
hyp1data$helpfulness <- helpfulness
```

Does that fix it?

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've found an even better way to solve it! See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error, but felt that the answer could be more descriptive. I believe the error arises because the `stats::anova()` and `car::Anova()` functions don't have the methods to recognize the `ordinal::clmm` model.

To run a Cumulative Link Mixed Model with`ordinal::clmm()` and obtain the follow-up deviance table, make sure to have both the `ordinal` and `RVAideMemoire` packages loaded. `RVAideMemoire` provides the methods to get the deviance table with `Anova.clmm()`.

```
# fake data
set.seed(5)
hyp1data <- data.frame(
  participant = c(paste0("id", 1:50),paste0("id", 1:50), paste0("id", 1:50),paste0("id", 1:50)),
  session = c(rep(1, 50), rep(2,50), rep(1, 50), rep(2,50)),
  reflectiontype = c(rep(1, 100), rep(2, 100)),
  helpfulness = sample(1:7, 100, replace = TRUE))

hyp1data[,1:3] <- lapply(hyp1data[,1:3], factor)
hyp1data$helpfulness <- factor(hyp1data$helpfulness, ordered = TRUE)

# load libraries
library(ordinal)
library(RVAideMemoire)

# use RVAideMemoire::Anova.clmm
hyp1.model1<-clmm(helpfulness~reflectiontype+session+(1+reflectiontype|participant),data=hyp1data)
summary(hyp1.model1) 
RVAideMemoire::Anova.clmm(hyp1.model1,type="II")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note another possible solution: I ran into the same problem when my data was called `df` - somewhere in the function call, this must have gotten confused with the df-function. Renaming my data frame solved it.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way to do an Analysis of Variance using package "RVAideMemoire" and package "car" using the tutorial:

Fabian Bross (2019). Using Mixed Effect Models to Analyze Acceptability Rating Data.
Version 1.0. Mimeo. Online: www.fabianbross.de/mixedmodels.pdf.

The section at the end describes very well how to follow up a clmm model in this way.

Comment: That's great - glad you've found a fix. Having said that, your question wasn't 'How do I do clmm' but 'why isn't my code working'. The point of the question archive is to provide possible fixes for other users, so if my answer fixed the question you actually asked, saying it fixed the problem (and wasn't some deeper clmm issue for example) is potentially useful to someone else later. Noting that there is a good guide elsewhere is definitely a really useful comment, but isn't really an answer to the specific question.